# How to create a notification when data from a websites HTML changed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I can pull information from a URL's HTML file more specifically the standings from the bracket site Challonge.com and store and display that information in a list view for an app using Xamarin forms.

Now what I'm trying to learn is how to update the list when the data from the HTML is updated. So when the standings on the site are updated I want to create a notification in my app that notifies the change in the standings.

I think I have to use an observable collection to detect changes in the HTML file? but I don't understand how it works or even if that would be the correct approach.

```
public async Task StartWebCrawl()
    {
        // var url = "http://challonge.com/lhswaterwars17/standings";
        var url = "http://challonge.com/jex0ymd2/standings";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        var divs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            .Equals("left display_name"))
            .ToList();

        var participants = new List<Particpants>();
        //var teamName = new List<String>();
        var teamStandings = new ObservableCollection<String>();

        foreach (var div in divs)
        {

            var participant = new Particpants
            {
                TeamName = div.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault().InnerText

            };

            participants.Add(participant);
        }
        foreach (var name in participants)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(name.TeamName);
            //teamName.Add(name.TeamName);
            teamStandings.Add(name.TeamName);
        }

        //ListView.ItemsSource = teamName;
        ListView.ItemsSource = teamStandings;
        teamStandings.CollectionChanged += HandleChange;

    }


    private void HandleChange(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Standings", "an Update occured", "Cancel");

    }



}
```

Comment: if you want to monitor for changes, you'll have to store the current results, periodically download the latest results, and then compare them to see if they have changed

Comment: Better yet, get a hash of the contents, and just compare hashes.

Comment: So how would I periodically get the latest results then? would I just keep calling the function every few seconds?

Comment: yes, you would have to use a timer to periodically request new data, unless there is some mechanism on the website to notify you of changes

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async Task StartWebCrawl()
    {

        var url = "http://challonge.com/jex0ymd2/standings";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        var participants = new List<Particpants>();
        ObservableCollection<String> listStandings = new ObservableCollection<string>();


        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {

            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                // Do the actual request and wait for it to finish.
                await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);



                // Switch back to the UI thread to update the UI
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    // Update the UI
                    var divs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("left display_name"))
                    .ToList();

                    foreach (var div in divs)
                    {

                        var participant = new Particpants
                        {
                            TeamName = div.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault().InnerText

                        };

                        participants.Add(participant);

                    }

                    foreach (var name in participants)
                    {

                        listStandings.Add(name.TeamName);
                    }
                    ListView.ItemsSource = listStandings;
                    // Now repeat by scheduling a new request
                    StartWebCrawl();
                });

            });

            // Don't repeat the timer (we will start a new timer when the request is finished)

            return false;
        });

    }
```